# How to get the role nodes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How can I get the role node of the "Blog-Autor"-Role and "Kommentar-Manager"-Role?

Or is there a way to do it more dynamicly with the role nodes?

My XML:

```
<roles>
    <role role="Administrator">
        <role role="Account Manager">
            <role role="Blog-Autor"/>
            <role role="Kommentar-Manager"/>
        </role>
    </role>
</roles>
```

And my php-code with which Im going through the XML from above:
(in the output_roles-function the $roles variable is only the first child, but I need both childs)(->children() don't help)

```
public function User_Roles() {
        $User_Type = $_SESSION["User_Type"];
        $xml_path = "./blog_config/blog_roles.xml";
        $xml_file = simplexml_load_file($xml_path);
        foreach ($xml_file->role as $role) {
            $role_attributes = $role->attributes();
            $user_role = (string) $role_attributes->role;
            if ($user_role == $User_Type) {
                $this->output_roles($role);
            }
        }
    }

private function output_roles($role) {
    foreach ($role as $current_role) {
        $role_ = $current_role->attributes();
        $role_type = (string) $role_->role;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><b>" . $role_type . "</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $roles = $role->role;
        $x = is_array($roles);
        if (is_array($current_role->role)) {
            $this->output_roles($current_role->role);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to get all inner-most roles given an ancestor role, you can do it  using xpath. For example :

```
$User_Type = "Administrator";
$roles = $xml_file->xpath("//role[@role='$User_Type']//role[not(role)]");
```

Above xpath return all `<role>` under `<role role="Administrator">` that doesn't have child element `<role>`, in other word the inner-most `<role>` elements.

Comment: so in this example $roles would be "Blog-Autor" AND "Kommentar-Manager"?

Comment: @Snickbrack exactly. See the demo : http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/sJ54Op

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an XPath expression, eg

```
$matches = $xml_file->xpath('//role[@role="Blog-Autor"]');
```

You can of course be more specific with the path, eg

```
$matches = $xml_file->xpath('/role[@role="Administrator"]/role[@role="Account Manager"]/role[@role="Blog-Autor"]');
```

but this should get you going.

See [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Comment: can I make it little more dynamic?

Comment: @Snickbrack you'll have to elaborate. Your question only asks how to find the two roles with `role` attributes "Blog-Autor" and "Kommentar-Manager"